# UICollectionViewCell issues with registerClass

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a collection view cell programmatically without the use of storyboards or nibs.

This is my cell .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestCVCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    UILabel *label;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label;

@end
```

and this is the .m file

```
#import "TestCVCell.h"

@implementation TestCVCell

@synthesize label;

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        if (!self.label) {
            label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
            label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

            self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            [self.contentView addSubview:label];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    self.label.text = @"";
}

@end
```

The issue I am having is that when I register class, it sporadically shows the cells and it doesn't show them at the correct locations. The cells will also randomly disappear/appear while scrolling (often not in the same location).

The weird thing is, if I create a nib and register the nib as opposed to the class, everything works perfectly fine.

The only difference I can think of between the nib and the class is with the nib, I use `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` instead of `-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`.

Here is the collection view files for reference

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestCollectionView : UICollectionView

@end
```

.m

```
#import "TestCollectionView.h"
#import "TestCVCell.h"

@interface TestCollectionView () <UICollectionViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *itemArray;

@end

@implementation TestCollectionView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame collectionViewLayout:[self collectionViewLayout]];

    if (self) {
        [self registerClass:[TestCVCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

        self.itemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        self.dataSource = self;

        for (int idx = 0; idx < 50; idx++) {
            [self.itemArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:idx]];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.itemArray.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TestCVCell *cell = (TestCVCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.itemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

    return cell;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(50, 50);

    return layout;
}

@end
```

Has anyone ever encountered this issue or something similar?

Thanks in advanced for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem, Your TestCVCell Class is initializing the label during init, then the collectionView is reusing the same cell, remember during reuse we don't initialize a new object, we just recycle an existing one, therefore your label is never set up on subsequent reuse. Make the following changes to your TestCVCell class.

TestCVCell.h

```
@interface TestCVCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic) UILabel *label;

@end
```

You don't need the iVar label anymore. We'll use the automatically synthesized _label iVar if need be.

Use lazy loading to initialize the label, its not only clever but a cleaner alternative, customize the getter to look like below, also remember to call super on prepareForReuse

```
#import "TestCVCell.h"

@implementation TestCVCell


- (UILabel *)label {

    if (!_label) {

        _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        _label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_label];

    }

    return _label;
}

- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.label.text = @"";
}

@end
```

The above code only adds the label to the contentView if its not been initialized before, it will only initialize a new one when needed, thus lazy loading. Delete your entire init method, it's not needed. The above is your entire implementation of TestCVCell. Clean and easy to understand.